# Get path of a Cloud Firestore document in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

In a situation like this where I am iterating through documents inside a collection of Cloud Firestore, how can I get the path of the documents?

```dart
children: snapshot.data.documents.map((document) {
  return ListTile(
    //want to get the document path here
    title: Text(document.path),
  );
```

Apparently, you can access the path data, but the explanation I found on github was very unclear
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/244

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking a *look at the source code*:

In [this line](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_snapshot.dart#L15) you can see that `_path` is a **private** property of ***`DocumentSnapshot`***.

Also, you can see that the `path` *is accessible* in a ***`DocumentReference`***, [here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_reference.dart#L31).

This results in the following code:

```
children: snapshot.data.documents.map((document) {
  return new ListTile(
    title: new Text(document.reference.path), // this will return the path
);
```

*Notice* how I *only added* `.reference`.